# Why is direct I/O file not being written to?

Tags: c, file, io

I am trying to understand direct I/O.  To that end I have written this little toy code, which is merely supposed to open a file and write a text string to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char thefile[64];
  int fd;
  char message[64]="jsfreowivanlsaskajght";
  sprintf(thefile, "diotestfile.dat");
  if ((fd = open(thefile,O_DIRECT | O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
          printf("error opening file\n");
          exit(1);
  }
  write(fd, message, 64);
  close(fd);

}
```

My compile command for Cray and GNU is

```
cc -D'_GNU_SOURCE' diotest.c
```

and for Intel it is

```
cc -D'_GNU_SOURCE' -xAVX diotest.c
```

Under all three compilers, the file diotestfile.dat is created with correct permissions, but no data is ever written to it.  When the executable finishes, the output file is blank.  The `O_DIRECT` is the culprit (or, more precisely I guess, my mishandling of `O_DIRECT`).  If I take it out, the code works just fine.  I have seen this same problem in a much more complex code that I am trying to work with.  What is it that I need to do differently?

Comment: There are usually alignment restrictions on the file offset and the read/write length when using `O_DIRECT`. The man page for the `open` function on your system will hopefully describe the details, which can vary both by operating system and file-system type.

Comment: Most likely write is returning -1 but you aren't checking for errors.

Comment: @stark  Well, yes, it is returning -1, but I don't have any further insight into the problem.

Comment: Have you tried other sizes? 512 (or multiples thereof) usually works on Linux.

Comment: @IanAbbott   Thanks, but 512 doesn't help.  I took it up to 4096 and got output, but it was junk.  Part of the string was in there, but not the whole string, and it was mainly junk.

Comment: So what is errno?

Comment: @stark   -1.  Doesn't tell me much!  But I found out something.  If interested, you can see where I answered the question myself.  If you have more info, though, I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: @bob.sacamento The question was, after `write` returned -1, what was `errno`?  That is, what did `perror()` print, or `strerror(errno)` return?  Those are vital functions to learn about: they *do* try to actually tell you why something failed, instead of just that meaningless -1.

Comment: @bob.sacamento The return value of a system call is *not* errno.  `errno` is a special other variable; it used to be a predefined global variable.  You want to `#include <errno.h>` and then, literally, call `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: @SteveSummit   Well, you really cleared something up for me.  THanks.  Unfortunately, errno translates into "Success"!   What???

Comment: @bob.sacamento Not sure what that means.  Are you saying it does this immediately after the call to `write()` has failed because you forgot to do the alignment thing?

Comment: `errno` is weird in several respects.  You should only try to use it *immediately after* certain system calls have failed -- that is, those system calls that are documented as setting `errno` when they fail.  (`write` is definitely one.)  See also [question 20.4](http://c-faq.com/misc/errno.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @SteveSummit  The alignment fixes the problem.  Without alignment, the code fails as I outlined, but `errno` still shows "Success" even though the write clearly fails.

Comment: @bob.sacamento That's definitely weird.  I see two possibilities: (1) your OS kernel has a significant bug, or (2) the code you newly wrote to inspect `errno` after `write` failure was wrong.  I would encourage you to post a second question: "`write` failed during direct I/O, but `errno` was 0".  Please include the exact code you used to call `write`, to check its return value, and to inspect `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

Going on Ian Abbot's comment, I discovered that the problem can be solved by adding an alignment attribute to the "message" array:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096
int bytes_to_write, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE;
bytes_to_write = ((MSG_SIZE + block_size - 1)/block_size)*block_size;
char message[bytes_to_write]  __attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCK_SIZE)));
```

(System I/O block size is 4096.)

So that solved it.  Still can't claim to understand everything that is happening.  Feel free to enlighten me if you want.  Thanks to everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to rethink the question, because your program runs perfectly on my system, and I cannot guess from it's listing where the error can be.

- Have you tested it before posting?
- if the program doesn't write to the file, probably a good idea is to see about the return code of `write(2)`.  Have you done this?  I cannot check because on my system (intel 64bit/FreeBSD) the program runs as you expected.

Your program runs, giving no output and a file named `diotestfile.dat` appeared in the `.` directory with contents `jsfreowivanlsaskajght`.

```
lcu@europa:~$ ll diotestfile.dat 
-rwx------  1 lcu  lcu  64  1 feb.  18:14 diotestfile.dat*
lcu@europa:~$ cat diotestfile.dat 
jsfreowivanlsaskajghtlcu@europa:~$ _
```